# Appending LI to a new UL in a string variable jquery

Tags: jquery

I've a UL having an id myul. I need to cut few LIs from it and needs to create a new UL.
So I filtered my UL by

```
var t=$('#myul li').filter(function(){
if(mycondition)
{
return true;
}
})
```

So here in t I've say 3 LIs been filtered from the main UL

I need to copy that selected LI to a variable which is like

```
var k="<div><ul id='mynewul'><ul><div>";
```

With my less knowledge I tried 
     $(t).appendTo($(k).find(ul));

But nothing happened or when I tried to find the number of LI in k by
     $(k).find('ul li').length;

It said 0.

So how can I accomplish that without affecting the main UL or simply how can I assign that to a variable as markup

Comment: S for Sandeep where is your H for Html???

Comment: @sforsandeep - Take a look at my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can wrap the filtered elements and then generate the HTML like so:

```js
var x = $('#myul li')
  .filter(function() {
    return $(this).text()[0] == 'b';
  })
  .clone()
  .wrapAll('<div><ul id="mynewul">')
  .parent().parent() // move up two elements
  .html()

console.log(x); // <ul id="mynewul"><li>bar</li><li>baz</li></ul>
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="myul">
  <li>foo</li>
  <li>bar</li>
  <li>baz</li>
  <li>qux</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: A little question.. Any scope of getting the mynewul UL's html markup using jquery after this wrapping without appending to body 
I mean $('#mynewul').html()??

Comment: @sforsandeep Yeah, you can get the resulting HTML via `.html()` ... note that the filtered elements aren't removed if you do that.

Comment: Waw.. Thanks.. No. I dont need that to be removed from the parent. I need that only in the newul

Comment: Oh.. I missed it.. Done.. :)

Comment: Something needs little tweek I think..
When I run the code it return the HTML in the variable. But the parent UL's filtered LIs being wrapped with DIV. That should not be happen.. Is that possible without affecting the parent UL

Comment: @sforsandeep Right, I forgot to clone the elements first :) good catch!

Comment: Thanks.. Its perfect now

Answer (score 1):

You have to wrap the element in jQuery, append it to the right element and then append the filters li's clone.

```
    //Filter all the lis you need
    var $lis = $('#myul li').filter(function(){
       if(mycondition)
       {
          return true;
       }
    });


   //Wrap and append to the page wherever you want
    var k="<div><ul id='mynewul'></ul><div>";
    $(k)
     .appendTo(document.body)
     .find('ul')
     .append($lis.clone());
```

Since I am cloning the li's it will not affect the original li's which is what you want.

**Demo** http://plnkr.co/edit/jKplpOHRzHM9Sk1a5NA1?p=preview